# in what model should i use transactions with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have 3 models (i'm working with zend 1.11, mysql), respectively 3 tables "category", "product" and "product_translate" that contains the translation labels of the product in some language, now there is one-to-many relationship between product and category(a product can be in only one category), and another one to many relation between product and product_translate. what i need is insert  a new category, then assign the last inserted id of this category into product table and the same thing goes with "product_translate", the best way i found to do this is by using transactions but i'm having troubles :
1/where should i put this trnasaction to insert all at once , in which model? "product","category" or "product_translate"?
2/how can i deal with the last inserted id since i'm going to need this several times especially with the translation table (because i'm goint to insert at least 2 new lines using the last inserted id of the product).
i hope i made my self clear, any help or suggestion is much appreciaited

Thankyou

Comment: Paragraphs, paragraphs, please!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this way

In your Controller/action

```
$category = new Category_model();
$lastinsertid = $category->categoryInsertFunction();
```

You can get the last insert id by calling this inside the model you want

```
$this->getDefaultAdapter()->lastInsertId();
```

return this value from categoryInsertFunction

And use the last insert id for other functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer so you suggest to use my transaction in the category model to insert into the 3 tables, i just have one question , doing that would'nt affect product_translate model since it has nothing to do with the category model? thnks